# Change font/style of JavaDoc in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc, android-studio-3.0

Android studio default style for JavaDoc have some problem with Persian(Iranian) comments;
The default font set for JavaDocs in Persian is not suitable and is not friendly readable that much.
I wonder when I can change this font or its style?

As you can see in the picture I've looked inside `Settings --> Editor --> Code Style --> Java -->JavaDoc`
but there is no settings for changing font and style.[image]

I'm using android studio 3.5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling italics for doc comments under **File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults > Comments > Doc comment > Text**.

Also try setting a different IDE font (main and fallback) under **File | Settings | Editor | Font**.

[image]